# ЛичОм или личЕм?

Tags: грамматика

Лич — в современном фэнтези маг-некромант, ставший нежитью, по одним версиям — после смерти, по другим — вместо смерти.
Как правильно - (кем?) личОм или личЕм?

Comment: А это русские "фантазеры" изобрели или что-то из англоязычного перетащили? Вот кто придумал/заимствовал, у того и надо спросить, как он его склоняет.   Склонение по сути есть результат договора. Если слово новое и способ склонения не очевиден - выбирайте на свой вкус.

Answer (score 2):

Поискал, заимствовано из английского. Этимология:

lich (n.)

also litch, lych, "body, corpse," a southern England dialectal survival of Old English lic "body, dead body, corpse," from Proto-Germanic *likow (source also of Old Frisian lik, Dutch lijk, Old High German lih, German Leiche "corpse, dead body," Old Norse lik, Danish lig, Swedish lik, Gothic leik), probably originally "form, shape," and identical with like (adj.).

[Сразу подумалось, что может быть связано с общеславянским "лихо" (горе, зло и т.д.), но по Фасмеру связь не прослеживается.]

В Интернете склоняют и так, и сяк, но "лИчем", кажется, чаще встречается. Ищите русский первоисточник, т.е. кто первым из авторов начал употреблять этот термин. В нём же ищите падежные формы.

Answer (score 1):

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87):
И. п. ли́ч; ли́чи
Р. п. ли́ча; ли́чей
Д. п. ли́чу; ли́чам
В. п. ли́ча; ли́чей
Т. п. **ли́чем**; ли́чами
П. п. ли́че; ли́чах

На этом [сайте](http://bezbukv.ru/inflect/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87) такое же склонение.

Из книг:
*Я посмотрел на точку, указанную [личем](https://books.google.ee/books?id=PDILDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT375&lpg=PT375&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=u3QqkqXNyz&sig=ACfU3U0bjVEUcVg12m-d0_Lw7eoyDayFdQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM18XkhKLiAhWtlYsKHYXnCIo4ChDoATANegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC&f=false).*
*Для того чтобы стать [личем](https://books.google.ee/books?id=lFTG2aPbF_EC&pg=PT349&lpg=PT349&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=ahK4GOMlqV&sig=ACfU3U1qkqFSkN13bTkH053a_xnn1idPbg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-__HChaLiAhWNp4sKHVNfA_c4FBDoATACegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC&f=false), нужно сначала умереть...*

Из статьи:
*...лишь отпетый злодей может стать [личем](http://old.mirf.ru/Articles/art3819.htm)...*